# How close are the extrema of $f(x)$ and $f(x) + \ln f''(x)$?

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Consider some suffiently often continuosly differentiable function $$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ such that $f''(x) > 0$ everywhere.
Then assume $f$ has a global minimum, which we will denote $x_f^*$.
Now consider the function
$$ g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$ x \mapsto f(x) + \ln f''(x).$$

If $g$ has a local/global minimum, let us denote it by $x_g^*$. Now I wonder how one could quantify how close $x_g^*$ and $x_f^*$ necessarily would have to be.

For example, let $f(x) = x^2 + u(x)$. Then one gets $g(x) = x^2 + u + \ln (2+u'')$. Taking derivatives, one would then want that

$$ x_f^* = (2x + u')^{-1}(\{0\}) \approx x_g^* \in (2x + u' + \frac{u'''}{2+u''})^{-1}(\{0\})$$

In the case that $u$ is a  polynomial of only even degrees, one should get that $\frac{u'''}{2 + u''}$ is small in comparison to $x$, so in this case I guess one would have some closeness of the minima. How can one generalize to arbitrary $u$?

Comment: "... Then $f$ has a global minimum" is not immediate.  For instance, $\mathrm{e}^x$ is continuously differentiable infinitely many times but has no global minimum on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @EricTowers you're right, I included it into the assumptions